# OCI8 OCI_FECTH_ARRAY returning no values no errors

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

Hi I am running a simple SQL statement to pull data and display using OCI_FETCH_ARRAY() with no luck. PHP doesnt log any error in error_log, or show no error message but shows just the blank page.

Table definition is as below:

Below is the SQL and i can run on SQL developer to pull relevant data:

```
$sql="SQL Here";
```

Error handling while running OCI_PARSE and OCI_EXECUTE functions below:

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn,$sql);

$error_msg_conn= oci_parse($conn,$sql);

if (!$error_msg_conn) {
  $e = oci_error($conn); 
  echo htmlentities($e['message']);
}

$error_msg_stmt = oci_execute($stid);

if (!$error_msg_stmt) {
  $e = oci_error($stid); 
  echo htmlentities($e['message']);
}
```

Code to display records from resultset below:

```
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid,OCI_RETURN_NULLS+OCI_BOTH))==TRUE) {

                echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row[4]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row[5]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row[6]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row[7]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row[8]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row[9]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row[10]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row[11]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row[12]."</td>\n";
                echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);

?>
```

Any idea why I don't see anything on the PHP output? Even no errors in the error_log?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you see any output at all?

Comment: I see only html headers printed which is outside the oci_fetch_array() loop. Nothing else. No errors nothing.

Comment: Do you see the start `<table>` tag in the source code?

Comment: Yes all HTML is printed fine. Strange that i can run same sql on sql developer and produces data. Also, all other php pages are working fine.

Comment: try just `while($row = oci_fetch_array($stid,OCI_BOTH)) {`

Comment: did that work for you?

Comment: Same. Not output no errors.

Comment: it doesnt like where clause. PHP pulls data without where clause fine. any idea why OCI8 would cause issue with " WHERE
        TRADE_DATE=TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YY')"?

Answer (score 1):

in your comment above you said

> it doesnt like where clause. PHP pulls data without where clause fine. any idea why OCI8 would cause issue with " WHERE TRADE_DATE=TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YY')"?

well thats because your TRADE_DATE column is a DATE not a VARCHAR

```
desc IRINS_COMPOSITE_INSTRUMENTS
Name                Null     Type          
------------------- -------- ------------- 
...
TRADE_DATE                   DATE
```

so doing `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YY')` creates a STRING which is then converted back to a DATE using your current NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting

assuming you are just trying to ignore the time component of `SYSDATE` try just changing it to

```
WHERE TRADE_DATE=TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

assuming that fixes it, it has nothing to to with OCI or OCI_FETCH_ARRAY()

Comment: Will try @ShoeLace your solution but when i do WHERE
  TRADE_DATE=TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE) it works fine.

Comment: it may work.. but its unpredictable.. compare date to date (and not date to char) and you should be fine.